# Bootstrap CSS row change in height causes jumping & usability trouble for everything below

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

With bootstrap it seems challenging to deal with variable height rows while remaining responsive in CSS.  In this case a variable number of articles will load into a carousel in sets of 4 or less depending on what is available in the database.

This causes all content below to jump around as the articles row height changes.

If I use relative positioning, or a set height for the div, it may cause the  CSS flow to error on different screen sizes. Say for example on phones when the carousel loads a single column of 4, rather than 2 columns of 2, the height is required to increase. I need some sort of min-height in the media query CSS append file, however, I couldn't get min-height to click on any div of this bootstrap carousel.

```
<!-- Articles -->

    <div id="articles" class="padding-bottom padding-top-two">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row"> <!-- Articles. -->
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="section-title">
                        <h1>Articles</h1>
                    </div>                  
                    <div id="articles-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#articles-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#articles-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#articles-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            <li data-target="#articles-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>                            
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">

                        <!-- Begin Loop -->
                            <!-- Every 4th post item && row, First one active -->
                            <div class="item active">
                                <div class="row">

<?php   
$stmt = $db->prepare("sql_string");
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->bind_result($VARIABLES))             
{
    $DIVCLOSE = true;
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {       
        ((**ommitted variable load section**))

        if($m == 4 || $m == 8 || $m == 12 || $m == 16)
        {
            echo "<div class='item'>";
            echo "<div class='row'>";
            $DIVCLOSE = true;
        }

        echo "<div class='col-sm-6'>\n";
        echo "<div class='single-post'>\n";
        echo "<div class='pull-left post-image'>\n";

        $Photo = "page_pics/$PICTURE";

        if(!file_exists($Photo) || $PICTURE == "")
                    $Photo = "images/placeholder.png";

            if(file_exists($Photo))
            {   
                    //$imgsize = getimagesize($Photo); 
                    //$intHeight=$imgsize[1];
                    //if($intHeight > 125)                  
                        //echo "<div style='height:125px;overflow:hidden'>\n";

                    echo "<a href='articles.php?item=$HEADER_URL&AID=$ID' alt='$HEADER'><img src='$Photo' class='img-responsive' style='width:auto;height:10%; float:right;' alt='$HEADER'/></a>\n";

                        //echo "</div>\n";                                  
            } // if pic exists
        /*  else
            {
                echo "<a href='articles.php?item=$HEADER_URL&AID=$ID' title='$HEADER' alt=$HEADER><h5 style='width:auto;height:25%; color:#454545;'><font style='color:#454545;'>$HEADER</font></h5></a>\n";                                                
            }
        } // if pic != ""
    }
        else
        {
                echo "<a href='articles.php?item=$HEADER_URL&AID=$ID' title='$HEADER' alt=$HEADER><h5 style='width:auto;height:25%; color:#454545;'><font style='color:#454545;'>$HEADER</font></h5></a>\n";                                                
        } */


        echo "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></a>\n";
        echo "</div>\n"; //.div class pull-left

        echo "<div class='pull-right post-details'>\n"; 
        echo "<a href='article_read.php?item=$HEADER_URL&AID=$ID' title='$HEADER, $ALT'><h5>$HEADER</h5></a>";

        echo "<p style='min-height:15%; max-height:15%'>$CONTENT";
        //if($CATEGORY!=$savedCat)
        echo "<h5>($CATEGORY)</h5>\n";
        echo "</p>";

        echo "</div>\n"; //div class pull-right
        echo "</div>\n"; //div class single-post
        echo "</div>\n"; //div class col-sm-6


        if($m == 3 || $m == 7 || $m == 11 || $m == 15 || $m == 19)
        {
            echo "</div>"; //item
            echo "</div>"; //row
            $DIVCLOSE = false;
            //echo "2222\n";                    
        }


    }

    if($DIVCLOSE)
    {
        echo "</div>"; //item
        echo "</div>"; //row            
    }
}

?>


                        </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
                    </div> <!-- /.articles-carousel -->                     
                </div><!-- /.col-md-10 End of articles -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!--/#recent-posts Articles-->

<!-- End Articles →
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a class that sets the height and width of the images coming in. You can then add the class to each `<li>` tag.

Comment: Thank you, Question, How would you suggest dealing with images of very different sizes in the db, when height needs to be so controlled to maintain responsive assembly of containers, rows, and col-XX?  Often when trying to use width:100%; (or height:100%; width:auto; )height:auto; overflow:hidden with various parent divs I would have problems with responsiveness of photos being centered, or worse ((and unrealistic)) matintaining a justified image grid.

Comment: My suggestion would be to give the carousel and underlying elements relative positioning. While I personally dislike using it, I don't deny its usefulness. Let the carousel take up a large area, so that any image would be able to fit without it having to re-size, then position the <div> (I'm assuming) below the carousel.

Comment: If I use relative positioning, or a set height for the div, it may cause the <div> stack to error on different screen sizes.  Say for example on phones when the carousel loads a single column of 4, rather than 2 columns of 2, the height is required to increase.  I need some sort of min-height in the media query CSS append file, however, I couldn't get min-height to click on any div of this bootstrap carousel.